# How to properly "clean" a UIView that was removed from Superview in Swift? - IOS

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiview, memory-leaks

I guess i might not understand how memory deallocates in Swift properly and thats why i wanted to ask this:
If i create a Message to the user using a UIView with a Label. i show it with an animation and then use ".removeFromSuperview()". when does it's memory deallocates? what are the conditions for it to deallocate? 
Im asking because if it doesn't deallocate until the app closes - it means that for the run of the app - each message shown and then hidden will take up memory for no good reason.

Thanks for anyone who explains :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views maintain a strong reference to their subviews. Once the subview is removed, the superview relinquishes this reference. If you have no other strong references the retain count will decrement to zero and the view will be released.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. just wanted to make sure it doesn't impact performance if i don't keep any strong reference to it